# Can the Black Obelisk's depiction of King Jehu tell us something about the appearance of ancient Israelites?

Tags: clothing, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, malchut-royalty

[The Black Obelisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Obelisk) depicts King Jehu in a subordinate position in front of the Assyrian king, Shalmeneser III. This is the oldest known portrayal of an Israelite.

Here we can see the King's style of dress.

[image: Jehu kissing the ground in front of Shalmaneser]

Have any Rabbinical authorities weighed in on whether they think this is an accurate depiction of an ancient Israelite? Can anything significant to Judaism be gleaned from this?

To my eye, everything on King Jehu appears to be standard, except for his cap. I find it interesting that it's fashioned so that a bun would form in the back. I haven't seen anything like it being worn by a Jew in recent history. Is there something similar?

Comment: I don't know what's in the Rabbinic literature, but Biblical Archaeology Review had an article on this exact subject last year:http://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/daily/ancient-cultures/ancient-near-eastern-world/israelite-kings-depicted-in-ancient-art/  .  The article's author seems to think it was a stylized depiction, since it looks almost the same as the one of the king above...he says it was showing tribute given from the Westernmost and Easternmost subject Kingdoms and probably not drawn from life...but that's just his opinion...nobody knows for sure..

Comment: @Gary this is really good. Why not post as an answer?

Comment: @user6591 -- because it doesn't really answer the question - next month they could print an article by another archaeology writer who could show his proofs for the case that it IS an accurate representation...I'd like to think it was carved by an eyewitness..it was pretty neat seeing it(and the older White Obelisk) just sitting there in the British Museum.  I gave him a pat on the head "Don't worry, we're still around Buddy, but the Assyrians smiling down on you aren't!"

Comment: ...also, I have no idea about the Rabbinic opinions and fashion parts of the question... That IS my favorite magazine! All sorts of good stuff in there usually...

Comment: @Gary I forgot the question requested Rabbinic opinions. But as far as your first reason, that wouldn't bother me. Each opinion stands on ots own merit and can be independent answers, notwithstanding which one is right. Eilu v'eilu..... lihavdil.

Comment: @Gary I also think its not a proper depiction. He has no taalis, no tephillin, and no magen david on his clothing:)

Comment: ...this guy did a purge, but he still had the calves set up.  Do you really think he'd wear tefillin, especially when kissing the feet or ground in front of another earthly King?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17068/discussion-between-gary-and-user6591).

Comment: The hat kind of looks like a [medieval Jewish hat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_hat), but we would be talking a 1800-2200 year time span, which seems awfully long for a clothing style.  It also resembles a [Phrygian cap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrygian_cap), but turned back, not forward.